# SQL - GROUP BY not working with DateName

Tags: sql

I'm trying to extract how many times a particular thing happened on each day of the week. Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT Source , Event, Qty, DateName(WEEKDAY,( TranDate )) As DayOfWk
FROM OurDB
GROUP BY Source, Event, DateName(WEEKDAY,( TranDate )), Qty
```

But it isn't grouping by Source (which only has two possible values). If I take out the DateName function, then everything groups correctly. Basically I'm looking to get:

- Source 1

  - Event 1

    - Monday - 15
    - Tuesday - 12
  - Event 2

    - Monday - 11
    - Thursday - 6
- Source 2

  - Event 1

    - Monday ...etc

EDIT: Added row data

OurDB:

- Source, Event, TranDate, Qty
- Phone, Coupon 1, 7/2/15, 6
- Internet, Coupon 4, 8/2/15, 2
- Internet, Coupon 1, 6/1/15, 5
- Internet, Coupon 1, 6/8/15, 4
- Phone, Coupon 2, 8/2/15, 4
- Phone, Coupon 1, 7/3/15, 10
- Internet, Coupon 1, 6/5/15, 3

Desired Output:

- Internet, Coupon 1, Monday, 9
- Internet, Coupon 1, Friday, 3
- Internet, Coupon 4, Sunday, 2
- Phone, Coupon 1, Thursday, 6
- Phone, Coupon 1, Friday, 10
- Phone, Coupon 2, Sunday, 4

Comment: Please show some row data

Comment: Added row data to original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Source , Event, max(Qty) --or min of qty
,DateName(WEEKDAY,( TranDate )) As DayOfWk
FROM OurDB
GROUP BY Source, Event, DateName(WEEKDAY,( TranDate ))
```

Your query didnot have a `aggregate` function. From the expected result, it looks like you have to use a `aggregate` function on Qty column.

Comment: I tried using that (except with SUM) and I'm still getting mixed results. The sources are all mixed up. What I tried:

`SELECT Source, Event, sum(Qty) As Qty, DateName(WEEKDAY,( TranDate )) As DayOfWk 
FROM Q_COUPONUSAGE
GROUP BY Source, Event, DateName(WEEKDAY,( TranDate ))`

Comment: you have to handle specifc weeks as well.or the results will be mixed up.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. With Source being first in the GROUP BY, I was under the impression that even if the results were mixed after that, that the Source field would stay grouped together. In regards to grouping by week, would that not cause multiple Saturday (or whatever day) entries? One for each week with records?

Comment: i thought you needed to see separate results for each week. If you don't need it the above query should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, might not have explained it well enough. I just need day of the week. When I run that query, the Source is not grouped. I honestly can't tell which column its grouping on. Just looks completely mixed up. If I remove the DateName from the query, everything looks perfect.

Comment: Actually, it is working. I just needed to put in an ORDER BY since the first time it sees some of the days is further down. So, looks like I'm good to go. Thank you!